# Can i add an animation from crazy talk 7 into a whole keynote presentation?

Tags: keynote, animation

I want to do a presentation with keynote and with Crazy talk 7, but i would like to know how to lay the animation over the entire keynote presentation, how can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

With CrazyTalk7 you can output your creations as videos or images in different sizes, resolutions and file formats. You can convert your work to an AVI file in DVD, HD, iPad and iPhone quality. You may also convert it into sequenced image (BMP/JPG/TGA/PNG) files to broadcast on a web server.

If you wish to import a photo or movie into Keynote the most convenient way to do it is by dragging the file directly into Keynote. Just drop it onto you slide.

You can also import media by choosing Insert > Choose from the top menu.

Hope this helps answer your question.

If you have any further questions please contact Reallusion Customer Support directly using the link below. The support team will gladly help you.

http://www.reallusion.com/CustomerSupport/User/QForm.aspx